# Downloading a file from a web link

Tags: javascript, database, url, fetch

I have some data Im trying to retrieve from a link I found online that provides a xlsx file upon visiting that link. Now what I'm trying to do is download that data and save it on to a database on a server I own. But I'm kind of lost on how to get the data. I was trying something like this

fetch(url).then(res => console.log(res)) // to see in the console if it is retrieving the file and it doesn't look like it is.

this isn't an api endpoint I'm trying to connect to its a url that downloads a file once you visit it.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!!

Comment: There is **necessarily** an API endpoint. If you're trying to save it on a database why don't you use a server language instead of a `fetch` in the browser?

Comment: fair enough. I think this is probably the right answer. Just looked up some php examples of my issue and it looks fairly straight forward. Thanks!!!